# Typescript compile not outputting to outDir option

Tags: typescript, npm, tsc

I am trying to setup a Typescript project and having difficulty compiling the project. I've set the outDir property to be dist in the current folder. I've tried running `build: echo \"Hello\" and pwd` along with `npm run build` which correctly outputs hello, and the current directory where tsconfig.json is located. 
My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": ["esnext.asynciterable", "es6", "es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

My package.json is:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules dist"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^11.13.4",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
```

No dist folder is created anywhere in my directory or anywhere it seems. There doesn't seem to be any errors on command line for the one ts file in my directory, nor any other specific files option that I am passing in to tsc. Am I initializing something incorrectly?

Comment: Can you try removing `baseUrl` and check whether it fixes the issue?

Comment: I did try that, and it still did not work. Though I did try running npm run compile, and then it was able compile and created the dist folder, but not sure why build did not run.